# Add a column description to a new (not Classic) PivotTable

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I want to add a column description to a PivotTable.

Is it possible with "new" (not old "Classic") PivotTable?

Here is source table example and desired results:

[image]

I can achieve the results with "Classic" settings but this has some feature I do not like so I would prefer to use "new" if possible:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Count of I2 manually` with formatting and in PIVOTTABLE TOOLS > DESIGN > Layout , Report Layout select *Show in Tabular Form* and if necessary uncheck Subtotal "line".